# All routes not accessible once angular5 app is deployed

Tags: deployment, angular5

I am deploying my angular5 app to hostable.com I have been able to successfully deploy the app to the server. I can visit the site with for example www.mysite.com but if I try to visit another page defined in the router such as www.mysite.com/anotherPage I get a Not found error.

However, if I place a button within the app that links to the www.mysite.com/anotherPage I can visit it that way.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me because the page I want to visit by entering it into the address bar is only for the owner of the site.

Does anyone know how I can get the page to be accessed by entering it in the address bar?

Thanks in advance Tony

Comment: I deployed using the CLI with: ng build --prod --base-href="base site url"

Comment: Is it working fine in local environment?

Comment: And check the requested URL in the browser console

Comment: Yes it is working fine in the local environment. when I go to each page such as localhost:4200/anotherPage I don't get any errors.

Comment: Have you seen which URL is getting generated for page not found?

Comment: Yes. Example would be www.mysite.com/anotherPage

Comment: how does your Route looks like? and project structure